# Not able to run cloudera VM using .vmdk on windows 10 machine

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, cloudera, bigdata

I am newbie in Big Data space. I downloaded cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.7.0-0-virtualbox from Cloudera and got Oracle virtual box where i have to setup remote space. But i am not able to run .vmdk file using VM. I am able to get it using .ovf file. I am not sure what is the issue here. Do i need to change some configuration for running this on machine (network or something else).
Adding error print in my post.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSOaq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Other users have reported similar problems using the .vmdk file. The workaround, which you have already done, is to import the .ovf file instead. The user experience should be the same, either way.

Comment: Thanks, Actually that post was to know the difference between using .vmdk file and .ovf. As i am not able to configure my settings in case .ovf (image) file. It comes with some default configuration and allocated 4GB RAM and 1 core. Is there an steps to increase or decrease those using .ovf file.

Comment: You would increase your RAM allocation in VirtualBox settings.